# Make a piece of heap memory read-only

Tags: c++

If I have a database application in C++. When the data size is small, it's easy to debug for bugs.
But when the data size becomes huge, and relationship becomes complex, the bug is very hard to debug, or hard to find the root cause of it. Sometimes the callstack can't tell you enough information to find the root cause, because the memory has been collapsed. It's very easy the memory of one component is written by other component. Only when the first component visit that memory, we met the crash, but it's too late.

The difficulty to find the root cause is proportional to the size of the handling data.

I am wondering if there is any tricks to predicate the risk, and protection code for avoid illegal memory written.

C++ pointer is a powerful tool, but it's also the high risk to use it. Any code could use the pointer to write/update the memory anytime. When one code write a memory, no other class object know it unless the class visit that memory,then find the value is already invalid, crashed.

If A hold a pointer to B, then some code write that memory to make the value to C.
Then when A use the B pointer to do something, invalid pointer.

I want to know, maybe it's impossible, if there some way to avoid this situation. Could we add some protection code there.

One method I thought could be is I could make the memory to be writable before change, after change make it readable. So other code can't write it, otherwise crash. This would help me to find the issue earlier.

Is there some way to make a piece of heap memory read-only?

Platform is windows. I hope I could use some switch in the code to control it's access right.

Comment: Please show some code.  The description is far too vague.

Comment: Overly broad, no real question. Flagging.

Comment: This is highly platform dependent, what is your current platform?

Comment: There's quite a lot of preamble which opens the gates to very broad responses, but "Is there some way to make a piece of heap memory read-only?" is clear, doesn't require any code to be shown, and has objective (implementation-specific) answers. It might be a dupe, but if not and if this gets closed, maybe ask that part of the question again on its own.

Answer (score 4):

I think the general trick here is separation of concerns.  If you can write small, independent pieces of code that you can have confidence in, and then connect these building blocks together in useful ways, it's a lot easier to have confidence in the results.

Confidence in the individual building blocks (classes, functions etc) can be boosted by unit tests.  This counts double for code that you expect to change :)

Without seeing any code it's a bit difficult to provide any directed suggestions, but my guess is that you have a high degree of coupling and low cohesion between your components, and your data encapsulation/ownership may also need work.  There is a lot of information available through google on how you might [deal with these kinds of issues](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/coupling.pdf).

Comment: In real world, the relationship between different component is hard to be simple, especially when the project becomes larger and larger. No one would refactoring the base design from ground up again. I need a practical way or pattern. Not unit test. In some complex data structures, the memory operation is very tricky. And debugging is more tricky, sometimes developer have to imagine, but not investigate the root cause.

Comment: Nobody said software was an easy profession. Avoiding complex, unmanageable datastructures is a skill learned in the real world.

Comment: memory operations shouldn't be tricky in good C++ code. Any trickiness points to weak places, avoid it until you can completely understand and control it

Comment: @giggle, Oh, OK.  Missed the edit where you made the question more specific.  Could you not use `shared_ptr` or similar, and call `reset()` when changing data?